# JS Redirect to page w/ postback or cache

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have a webforms site that has 2 menus.

On a page you click a button, has some c# events fired by a webservice (ajax) then redirects you to another page with `history.go(-1)`. The only problem is that in the webservice I create a sesion that makes the menus switch, the default one hides and the other one shows. The menu switch in done in the Page_Load of the Master page.

My problem is that with history.go(-1) you get to the previous page, but the old menu is present instead of the new one. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fix was to add in a session the previos link, and when I need a redirect w/ cache I redirect to another aspx page, that redirects depengind on the url params where I need it to go... it was the simpler method I could thing of...

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the browser is not actually loading the previous page it is using the cached page. is there a reason you can not have both menus hidden and then decide what one to show client side? this way you can let the JS .ready take care of what menu to show and then you should get the desired results when using the history.go(-1).

[This artical](http://monket.net/blog/2010/02/detecting-when-a-page-is-loaded-from-the-browser-cache/) speakes to setting cookie from the server then checking in on the client.
you could use something like this and then check the cookie to determine if the page was loaded from cache and then force a postback.

```
location.reload()
```

Comment: I can't make thoes changes... the second menu is only availabe if the user is logged in, and for security reasons it's rendered on server side... can I call a server redirect from a webservice? (.asmx.cs) ?

Comment: @Andrew, another possible solution for you.